# How to use a re-usable frame class in tkinter?

Tags: python, tkinter

I want to have a reusable frame with widgets within one of my screens (I'm going to reuse that frame later in another screen). That frame will be part of the screen, there will be additional widgets.

I tried creating a class for the reusable frame (class FrameBovenverdieping(tk.Frame):) which should be shown in the screen ViewBezettingBoven. However, the FrameBovenverdieping shows in each screen, also in StartPage and PageTwo. I want to have it only in ViewBezettingBoven.

Also, when I'm on ViewBezettingBoven, the buttons to switch screens don't work anymore

```
import tkinter as tk

PLATTEGROND_BOVEN_WIDTH = 1000
PLATTEGROND_BOVEN_HEIGHT = 720
PLATTEGROND_BENEDEN_WIDTH = 1000
PLATTEGROND_BENEDEN_HEIGHT = 720


class BezettingApp(tk.Tk):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):

        tk.Tk.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)

        self.geometry("{0}x{1}+0+0".format(self.winfo_screenwidth(), self.winfo_screenheight()))
        self.bind("<Escape>", lambda e: e.widget.quit())

        container = tk.Frame(self)      
        container.pack(side="top", fill="both", expand = True)
        container.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
        container.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1)

        self.frames = {}

        for F in (StartPage, ViewBezettingBoven, PageTwo):

            frame = F(container, self)

            self.frames[F] = frame

            frame.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky="nsew")

        self.show_frame(StartPage)

    def show_frame(self, cont):

        frame = self.frames[cont]
        frame.tkraise()


class StartPage(tk.Frame):

    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self,parent)
        label = tk.Label(self, text="Start Page")
        label.pack(pady=10,padx=10)


        button = tk.Button(self, text="Visit Page 1",
                        command=lambda: controller.show_frame(ViewBezettingBoven))
        button.pack()

        button2 = tk.Button(self, text="Visit Page 2",
                        command=lambda: controller.show_frame(PageTwo))
        button2.pack()


class ViewBezettingBoven(tk.Frame):

    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)

        label = tk.Label(self, text="Page One!!!")
        self.parent = parent
        self.window = FrameBovenverdieping(self)


        label.pack(pady=10,padx=10)
        self.widgets()

    def widgets(self):

        button1 = tk.Button(self, text="Back to Home",
                        command=lambda: controller.show_frame(StartPage))
        button1.pack()

        button2 = tk.Button(self, text="Page Two",
                        command=lambda: controller.show_frame(PageTwo))
       button2.pack()

class FrameBovenverdieping(tk.Frame):

    def __init__(self, parent):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)
        self.parent = parent
        self.widgets()

    def widgets(self):
        photo = tk.PhotoImage(file='autplacement.png')
        w = PLATTEGROND_BENEDEN_WIDTH
        h = PLATTEGROND_BENEDEN_HEIGHT
        imagelabel = tk.Label(image=photo)
        imagelabel.image = photo
        imagelabel.pack()

class PageTwo(tk.Frame):

    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)
        label = tk.Label(self, text="Page Two!!!")
        label.pack(pady=10,padx=10)

        button1 = tk.Button(self, text="Back to Home",
                        command=lambda: controller.show_frame(StartPage))
        button1.pack()

        button2 = tk.Button(self, text="Page One",
                        command=lambda: controller.show_frame(ViewBezettingBoven))
        button2.pack()



app = BezettingApp()
app.mainloop()
```

Output:

```
Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Lonneke Kolkman\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1705, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
  File "C:\Users\Lonneke Kolkman\Google Drive\Assortimens\BezettingAppPy\bezettingapp.py", line 74, in <lambda>
    command=lambda: controller.show_frame(StartPage))
NameError: name 'controller' is not defined
Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Lonneke Kolkman\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1705, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
  File "C:\Users\Lonneke Kolkman\Google Drive\Assortimens\BezettingAppPy\bezettingapp.py", line 78, in <lambda>
    command=lambda: controller.show_frame(PageTwo))
NameError: name 'controller' is not defined
>>>
```

The program runs, but shows the reusable frame within each page though I want it only to show within ViewBezettingBoven.

Comment: I rolled back your edit because it invalidates the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Your controller variable is out of scope. If you send controller to the function I can run the code without errors:

```
class ViewBezettingBoven(tk.Frame):

    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)

        label = tk.Label(self, text="Page One!!!")
        self.parent = parent
        self.window = FrameBovenverdieping(self)


        label.pack(pady=10,padx=10)
        #send controller to function
        self.widgets(controller)

    def widgets(self,controller):

        button1 = tk.Button(self, text="Back to Home",
                        command=lambda: controller.show_frame(StartPage))
        button1.pack()

        button2 = tk.Button(self, text="Page Two",
                        command=lambda: controller.show_frame(PageTwo))
        button2.pack()
```

Comment: Thanks. Now, how can I use a reusable Frame class?